# Create array of arrays from array of objects in the style of a matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. I am trying to create a matrix-like array of objects.

This is my code:

```js
let data = [
    {device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
    {device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
    {device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
    {device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
    {device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
    {device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12}
    ];

let arr = data.map(d => Object.values(d));
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I do the map like above, I am getting all the object values into the array of arrays.

How do I make my data look like this:

```
    arr = [
        [0,0,67], [0,1,23],[0,2,10],[0,3,67],[0,4,23],[0,5,10],
        [1,0,78], [1,1,12],[1,2,20],[1,3,78],[1,4,12],[1,5,20],
        [2,0,12], [2,1,14],[2,2,30],[2,3,12],[2,4,14],[2,5,30],
        ]
```

Not sure how to make my array objects look like the matrix above.

Comment: Please make your question more clearer!

Comment: @TopW3, I just want to convert my array of objects to look like the matrix (arr) like above. I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get just the numeric values from each object use `Array.filter()`, and ignore value that are `NaN` (not a number):

```js
const data = [{"device":"iphone","site":"google","val1":10,"val2":20,"val3":30},{"device":"iphone","site":"bing","val1":23,"val2":12,"val3":14},{"device":"iphone","site":"jeeves","val1":67,"val2":78,"val3":12},{"device":"ipad","site":"google","val1":10,"val2":20,"val3":30},{"device":"ipad","site":"bing","val1":23,"val2":12,"val3":14},{"device":"ipad","site":"jeeves","val1":67,"val2":78,"val3":12}];

const arr = data.map(d => Object.values(d).filter(v => !isNaN(v)));

console.log(arr);
```

To get your matrix - reverse the array, map the objects, and then map the values after filtering them, and use the indexes. Flatten the results one level, and sort according to the 1st value of each sub-array in the matrix.

```js
const data = [{"device":"iphone","site":"google","val1":10,"val2":20,"val3":30},{"device":"iphone","site":"bing","val1":23,"val2":12,"val3":14},{"device":"iphone","site":"jeeves","val1":67,"val2":78,"val3":12},{"device":"ipad","site":"google","val1":10,"val2":20,"val3":30},{"device":"ipad","site":"bing","val1":23,"val2":12,"val3":14},{"device":"ipad","site":"jeeves","val1":67,"val2":78,"val3":12}];

const arr = [...data]
  .reverse()
  .map((d, y) => 
    Object.values(d)
      .filter(v => !isNaN(v))
      .map((v, x) => [x, y, v])
  )
  .flat(1)
  .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b);
  
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but the result does not look like `arr` I want. It should look like a matrix `[
        [0,0,67], [0,1,23],[0,2,10],[0,3,67],[0,4,23],[0,5,10],...`

Comment: What is the logic behind transforming it to a matrix?

Comment: That's exactly what this code is doing...? Unless you mean that some how the `10, 20, 30` in the first object should somehow return `0, 0, 67`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes so `0,0,67` is basically (xaxis position, yaxis position, value)

Comment: @OriDrori, i am trying to create a heatmap of the data. Thats the data you send in for heatmaps using highcharts

Comment: Check the order of the items. It's not the same as yours. I've added a sort by the X value to fix the order.